# Why Dragon windows cannot be cleaned with hydrogen peroxide or acetone?

Tags: dragon-v2, spacecraft-window

As you can see in the photo below, there is a small label which says: "Do not clean windows with hydrogen peroxide or acetone". Why is that and what can be used instead of those chemicals to clean the windows? Water, maybe? Do astronauts have something on board to clean these windows if they get dirty?

[image]

Comment: Acetone is a very good solvent and often damages a variety of plastics.

Comment: I made the mistake of cleaning a CD with acetone once @AJN. Oops.

Comment: possibly an oleophobic coating? Those do not agree with peroxide, and the underlying polymer plastic of the window is not friends with Acetone.

Comment: You definitely don't want to clean it with both at the same time... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone_peroxide

Comment: Those are both potentially fairly harsh chemicals. Isopropyl alcohol or detergent-based cleaners might be more appropriate.